# Yii2 orderBy specific values

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

Here's my controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = users::find();
    $count = count($users);
    $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count, 'pageSize'=>20]);
    $models = $query->offset($pagination->offset)
    ->limit($pagination->limit)
    ->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('FIELD (mission, Leader, Right Hand, QA, Member)')])
    ->all();
    return $this->render('index', [
        'models' => $models,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]);
 }
```

But it not working. I keep getting this error

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Hand, QA, Member) LIMIT 16 OFFSET 16' at line 1
>   The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY FIELD (mission, Leader, Right Hand, QA, Member) LIMIT 16 OFFSET 16

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: You should update Right Hand column name to Right_Hand because yii won't support space between name.

Answer (score 0):

if you need  order by FIELD(column, string....) you should use  quote around values

```
->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression("FIELD (mission, 'Leader', 'Right Hand', 'QA', 'Member')")])
```

Comment: Thank you :) Don't get the error anymore but data is not sorted